# Scaling buttons without losing the 3D effect

Tags: android, button, scaling

Is there a way to scale buttons in such a way that the do not loose their 3D effect. Since everything is beeing scaled proportionally the 3D border of a button becomes too large when the button scale changes.

On iPhone there is an attribute that can be set so that this does not happen and the button looks good in whatever size.

Is there anything like this on Android?

Or how would one setup a button so that scaling looks good all the time?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make [9-patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#NinePatch) button backgrounds using [draw-9 patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) in the Android SDK bin folder.  These will scale very nicely from a very small sample/drawable.

Comment: I created a 9 patch button now and it looks OK in  9-patch on the MAC. But when I start the app it looks totally different and streched incorrectly. Any idea what could be the reason?